Magento 2.4.7 Catalog Price Rule is not working with customer groups
i have crated one catalog price rule as below:
Websites : Main Website
Customer Groups : Wholesale, Destributer 1, Destributer 2
From : 06/18/2012
Priority : 0
Conditions : Attribute set is not custom
Actions : Apply as percentage of original
Discount Amount : 13.043500
Discard subsequent rules : Yes
All this conditions are fulfilled, still sometimes i don't get applied rule price(special price) sometimes.
when i didn't get that special price, i didn't get customer group id from followin file path : Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule.php
 public function getRulePrices(\DateTimeInterface $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds)
        {
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            $select = $connection->select()
                ->from($this->getTable('catalogrule_product_price'), ['product_id', 'rule_price'])
                ->where('rule_date = ?', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId)
                ->where('customer_group_id = ?', **$customerGroupId**)
                ->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds, \Zend_Db::INT_TYPE);
    
            return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
        } 


The issue you’re encountering with the special price not being applied sometimes could be due to several factors related to how Magento 2 handles catalog price rules and customer groups. Below are a few troubleshooting steps and considerations:

Customer Group ID Issue:

Ensure that the customer group ID being passed to the getRulePrices function is correct and matches the ID for the customer group associated with the logged-in user. If the ID is incorrect, the special price will not be applied.
You can debug the value of $customerGroupId before the query is executed to ensure it is correctly set.


Cache and Indexing:

Catalog price rules are heavily dependent on the indexing and caching mechanism in Magento. If the indexes are not properly updated, the special prices might not reflect correctly. Make sure to reindex and clear the cache:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush


Also, ensure that cron jobs are running properly since catalog price rules are processed by cron.


Overlapping Rules:

If there are overlapping catalog price rules with the same priority or rules that could potentially conflict, Magento might not apply the correct rule. Check if there are any other rules with the same priority or that could affect the products in question.


Debugging the Query:

You can log the SQL query being generated by the getRulePrices function to see if it’s returning the expected results:
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from($this->getTable('catalogrule_product_price'), ['product_id', 'rule_price'])
    ->where('rule_date = ?', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId)
    ->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId)
    ->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds, \Zend_Db::INT_TYPE);

$query = $select->__toString(); // Log this query for debugging




Rule Application Date:

Check the date when the rule is supposed to be applied (rule_date). Ensure that the From date and To date of the rule are correct, and that the rule is active during the time you are testing.


Multiple Websites and Stores:

If your Magento instance has multiple websites or stores, ensure that the rule is correctly assigned to the relevant website and store view. The website_id parameter in the query needs to match the current website context.


Discount Rounding:

The discount amount of 13.043500 might cause rounding issues or precision errors in some cases. Consider using a simpler discount value to see if that resolves the issue.


Third-Party Extensions:

If you are using any third-party extensions that modify catalog pricing or customer groups, they might interfere with the rule application. Check if disabling such extensions affects the outcome.



By addressing these points, you should be able to diagnose why the special price sometimes does not apply as expected.
